# A regular expression that matches strings that don't start with a set of words

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regular expression that matches strings that start with either the word "db" or the word "admin":

```
/^\/(db|admin)\//
```

I'm refactoring my code and my requirements have changed: Now I need the opposite, i.e. a regular expression that matches strings that **don't** start with one of those two words. Is this possible with regular expressions?

Note: I cannot use JS API - the regular expression is inserted in Express.js's `app.all(path, callback)` method directly (as the `path`).

Comment: you just want a true/false test (using the full string after testing)?

Comment: @GitaarLAB Yes, it's just a true/false test. the strings are HTTP request paths, and the regular expression should match all paths except those that start with either "/db/" or "/admin/".

Comment: Yes I think I agree that the `(?!)` look-ahead in that linked possible duplicate would work here.

Comment: @GitaarLAB I have to provide a regular expression, and then Express.js uses it on the request paths to perform the test.

Comment: @Pointy `^\/(?!admin|db)` seems to be it.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to Nico for pointing out that JavaScript RegExp has `(?!)` functionality. The solution seems to be:

```
/^\/(?!admin|db)/
```

---

[image]

Comment: Do you perhaps want to include the `/` inside the lookahead? Like, `/^\/(?!(?:admin|db)\/)/`? That way you'd allow "/administrator/" (which may or may not be important to you).

Comment: @Pointy Yes, this is a slight improvement :) (With this, I will also catch "/admin" or "/db" but those paths don't make sense anyway.)